# Creating a Pivot Table using VBA into an existing sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table in vba into an existing workbook. The VBA code is in its own workbook, and the source data and destination for the pivot table are in another workbook Sheets(1), Sheets(2) respectively.

Below is my attempted code, but I am receiving Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument on the last line :( Also, I realize I have bad variable names, sorry...This is my first Macro and will optimize going forward!

Please see my attempt below and kindly assist!

```
Public CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal As Workbook
Sub CashBreaksSummaryTab3()

Dim CountRows2 As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

CountRows2 = CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("I" & CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Worksheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Activate
  SrcData = CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Sheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("B5").Address & ":" & CashBreaksMetricsWorkbookFinal.Sheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Metrics").Range("I" & CountRows2).Address

'Set Sheet with Pivot
  Set sht = Sheets("CSCIG_Cash Breaks Summary")

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A4").Address

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPvt)

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=sht.Range("A4"))` and skip the Address part.   If you want to use the address, then sheet names with spaces need to be quoted using single quotes.